# Resolving an observable inside `switchMap` in NGRX effect

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm caching some data using NGRX like this:

```
@Effect() public getProductList$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType<actionType>(actions.ACTION_NAME),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select(x => x.storeSlice), (action: any, store: any) => store.data),
        switchMap((data: any) => {
            if (data.items.length > 0) {
                return [new actions.Success(data.items)];
            }

            const localData: any[] = localStorage.getItem(...);

            if (localData != null) {
                return [new actions.SuccessAction(localData)];
            }
            else {
                return this.apiService.getAll()
                    .pipe(
                        map(result => new actions.Success(result)),
                        catchError(error => actions.Failure(error));
            }
        })
    );
```

Basically, I try to get the data from the store first, if the resulting array has items, I return a Success action with the data. Otherwise, I try to load the data from the `localStorage` and if it exists I return the success action with it. Finally, if there is no cached data, I call the API to get the data, and this can result in a Success or Failure action.

The problem is that the data grew too much and I can't store it in the `localStorage` anymore, so I need to use `IndexedDb`, which works with promises.

I created a wrapper service around the `IndexedDb api` and my method returns an `Observable` with the data. So I need to switch the `const localData: any[] = localStorage.getItem(...);` with my service call. With the `localStorage` everything is fine since it is synchronous, but the `IndexedDb` is not.

I tried something like this, but it does not work:

```
@Effect() public getProductList$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType<actionType>(actions.ACTION_NAME),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select(x => x.storeSlice), (action: any, store: any) => store.data),
        switchMap((data: any) => {
            if (data.items.length > 0) {
                return [new actions.Success(data.items)];
            }

            return this.idb.getData().map(localData => {
                if (localData != null) {
                    return [new actions.SuccessAction(localData)];
                }
                else {
                    return this.apiService.getAll()
                        .pipe(
                            map(result => new actions.Success(result)),
                            catchError(error => actions.Failure(error));
                }
            });


        })
    );
```

This does not work because I'm returning an Observable instead of the actual `action`. But how could I extract the data out of the `Observable`? Is there an rxjs operator that could help me with this?

---

If anyone gets here in future, this was the solution:

```
@Effect() public getProductList$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType<actionType>(actions.ACTION_NAME),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select(x => x.storeSlice), (action: any, store: any) => store.data),
        switchMap((data: any) => {
            if (data.items.length > 0) {
                return [new actions.Success(data.items)];
            }

            return this.idb.getData()
                .pipe(
                    map(data => new actions.SuccessAction(data),
                    switchMap(successActionFromIDB => {
                        if (successActionFromIDB.payload.length > 0) {
                            return of(successActionFromIDB);
                        }
                        else {
                            return this.apiService.getAll()
                                .pipe(
                                    tap(data => this.idb.setData(data)),
                                    map(data => new actions.SuccessAction(data)),
                                    catchError(error => new actions.FailureAction(error))
                                )
                        }
                    })
                )
            );
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
@Effect() public getProductList$ = this.actions$
    .pipe(
        ofType<actionType>(actions.ACTION_NAME),
        withLatestFrom(this.store.select(x => x.storeSlice), (action: any, store: any) => store.data),
        switchMap((data: any) => {
            // Return value as an observable with of()
            if (data.items.length > 0) {
                return of([new actions.Success(data.items)]);
            }

            const localData: any[] = localStorage.getItem(...);

            if (localData != null) {
                // Return value as an observable with of()
                return of([new actions.SuccessAction(localData)]);
            }

            // Return value as an observable with 
            return this.apiService.getAll()
                .pipe(
                    map(result => [new actions.Success(result) as any]),
                    catchError(error => [actions.Failure(error) as any])
                );
        }),
        // Flat map the observable result from the switchMap. This will flatten 
        // your result to an actual value.
        flatMap(data => data)
    );
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm getting an error on the flatMap line: `Type 'action.Success | action.Failure | action.....' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'`. If I try to cast data as `any` to ignore the error, then I get the following error at runtime: `core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

Comment: I updated my answer. I forgot to return the last results as an array as well.

Comment: Does the actions.Success(result) and actions.Failure(error) return an array or single object?

Comment: Your new answer doesn't even call the indexedDb service, which is the service that is causing me all the trouble. But your first answer gave me some light and I could come up with a solution. Thank you so much! I updated the question with the solution.